# Can Ram and Sarayu be brother and sister?

Tags: gods, name

If a kid name is Ram then can her sister name be Sarayu? Please suggest.

We require this to name a girl child.

We got a dream about Sarayu river after we come to know about pregnancy in last year.

We thought the we got this dream might be because we named other kid as Ram, and luckily now its a girl child.

Comment: Sarayū is a female name. But it's upto you if you want to name your daughter after a river. Based on Manusmṛti (3.9), it's not proper to name the girl child after a river, nakṣatra, etc.

Comment: @Bingming These river names are used as female baby names as far as I know: Ganga, Yamuna, Saraswati, Kaveri, Narmada. They may also be names of river personification goddesses.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already familiar with that. @ruben2020 People name their babies pretty randomly these days, I just mentioned a śāstrīya opinion and left the choice up to the OP